# How to clear up the Dashboard stats in Magento 1.9

Tags: database, magento-1.9, dashboard, sample-data

How to clear up the Dashboard stats in Magento 1.9, which shows a lot of total sales? I got hold of some mysql statements, but in Magento 1.9 the table names don't match.

Comment: Which tables does not match?

Comment: I figured out that the tables in the script were for an older version of Magento, guess for 1.3 or so. Will try the links given by Dexter. Hope works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Raw queries or script use one of the extension listed below:

1) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/seamless-delete-order.html

2) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

3) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/orders-eraser.html

They will delete all the unwanted and dummy orders. To remove search terms, you can goto Catalog->Search Terms and delete all of them.

Comment: all the 3 links have not helped me delete the orders in Magento 1.9 as "Seamless" and "Delete-Orders" don't show as supported for version 1.9 and give an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in /home/hostdrome/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container.php on line 66"...... whereas "Wyomind Orders Eraser" got installed fine, but the list of actions in its demo shows "Delete" option, but it doesn't come for me. Do I need to do any settings after installing Orders-Eraser?

Comment: I have used Wyomind for my websites in 1.9. It works fine... there is no setting required to be done.. you will see the delete option as a drop down in Sales->Order section under Actions..